# Unmerge and copy down across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I found the following code on this site to be very helpful

```
Public Sub UnmergeAndFill()
    With Selection
        If .MergeCells Then
           .MergeCells = False
           Selection.Cells(1, 1).Copy
           ActiveSheet.Paste 'Or PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to get it to perform this action across all worksheets in a workbook with no luck.

Here is what I have. It still seems to only do the action on the active worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub UnmergeAndFill()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Selection
           If .MergeCells Then
               .MergeCells = False
               .Selection.Cells(1, 1).Copy
               .ActiveSheet.Paste 'Or PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
           End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: It's most likely because you're using `Select`. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? Your loop did not reference the loop variable `ws`, and there is no need to Select anything.

```
    Sub UnmergeAndFill()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, r1 As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            If IsNull(.MergeCells) Or .MergeCells Then
              On Error Resume Next                
              For Each r In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                    If r.MergeCells Then
                        Set r1 = r.MergeArea
                        r.UnMerge
                        r1.Value = r.Value
                    End If
              Next r
             on error goto 0
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    End Sub
```

Comment: This does not seem to do anything. But it could be the guy running it  :)

Comment: It unmerges cells, when I do it at least. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It appears to run and does not throw any errors but each worksheet in the workbook appears untouched

Comment: Can you merge some cells on a sheet manually and then run it and see what happens.

Comment: I created a new tab and merged a few cells and ran it and it did not error out or throw any errors but it did not unmerge the cells. The worksheet remained as it was before it was run

Comment: Strange. Do you have any other workbooks open? If not, can you try replacing `UsedRange` with `Cells`.

Comment: Still nothing. I did run the following and it worked but only on the active sheet. Can't seem to get it to work on all sheets in the workbook

Comment: Sub UnmergeAndFill()
     Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range
      For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
            cell.MergeCells = False
            joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
        End If
      Next
    End Sub

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - it's unreadable. I've amended the code above - can you try it now?

Comment: Sorry about that. The revised code does unmerge all of the cells in the workbook. But it does not copy the values to the newly empty cells

Comment: Ah I missed that bit. What should go where?

Comment: basically whatever was in the merged cells should go into all the cells that were unmerged

Comment: Amended again above, was more involved than I thought. Ended up using special cells as merged cells show up as blanks.

Comment: Glad we got there in the end. Perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: How do I do that? :)